# How to compare number in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, tasm

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data

STR1 DB 'Enter the first number: $';
STR2 DB 'Enter the second number: $';
STR3 DB 'Number 1 is greater than number 2$';
STR4 DB 'Number 1 is less than number 2$';
STR5 DB 'Number 1 is equal to number 2$';

KB_INPUT LABEL BYTE
MAX_LEN DB 20
ACT_LEN DB ?
KB_DATA DB 20 DUP ('$')

KB1_INPUT LABEL BYTE
MAX1_LEN DB 20
ACT1_LEN DB ?
KB1_DATA DB 20 DUP ('$')

.code

main proc far
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

LEA DX, STR1
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H


MOV AH,01H
LEA DX, KB_INPUT
INT 21H


MOV DL, 0DH
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H

MOV DL, 0AH
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H

LEA DX, STR2 
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H


MOV AH,01H
LEA DX, KB1_INPUT
INT 21H


MOV DL, 0DH
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H

MOV DL, 0AH
MOV AH, 02H
INT 21H

mov al, KB_DATA+0
CMP al,KB1_DATA+0
JE eqll
JG gtr
JL lesss

eqll:
LEA DX, STR5
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

gtr:
LEA DX, STR3
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

lesss:
LEA DX, STR4
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H

exit:
mov ax,4C00H
int 21h
main endp
end main
```

I want to display which are the relationship between two numbers. But when I enter '5' for number 1 and '4' for number 2, errors appears, why??

Comment: What errors? Please be more specific.

Comment: Assembly languange for what processor or microcontroller?

Comment: x86: Use "ja gtr"  for jump above + "jb lesss" for jump below.

Comment: If you are willing to add a short simple comment on each line of code, I am willing to look over this question and see if I know something that can help you.

Comment: @ferrangb it's tagged `tasm` so I would assume x86.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a JMP after each case like

```
eqll:
LEA DX, STR5
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H
JMP exit
```

Without the JuMP instruction after each message that you display, the processor will continue running and printing the other messages too.
It's like writing switch(..)  case: ... in a high level language but forgetting to put break after each case statement. 
I assume that is what you mean by errors, that you get multiple messages?